# For loops into LINQ... possible?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the following code which counts the appearances of cards based on type:

```
// counters initialization
var counters = new Dictionary<int, int>();
for (int i = 2; i <= 14; i++)
  counters.Add(i, 0);

// loop through and count number of appearances
for (int i = 0; i < playerCards.Length; i++)
  counters[playerCards[i]]++;

// Eg output: 
// playerCards = { 9, 9, 3, 3, 10 }
// counters = ( (2, 0) , (3, 2) , (4, 0) , (5, 0) , (6, 0) , (7, 0) , 
//              (8, 0) , (9, 2) , (10, 1), (11, 0), (12, 0), (13, 0), (14, 0) )
```

Is there a solution for this with LINQ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works quite well:

```
var playerCards = new [] { 9, 9, 3, 3, 10 };

var lookup = playerCards.ToLookup(x => x);

var counters = Enumerable.Range(2, 13)
    .ToDictionary(x => x, x => lookup[x].Count());
```

I got this result:

[image: counters]

If you're happy to forgo the lookup, then this will work too:

```
var counters = Enumerable.Range(2, 13)
    .ToDictionary(x => x, x => playerCards.Count(y => y == x));
```

Answer (score 5):

Faster? No. LINQ will seldom make your code faster, unless you can benefit from parallelization or lazy evaluation.

Often, the main benefit will be that your code will be easier to read (subjective, perhaps). But in this case, I think your code is about as clear as it can be. Converting it to LINQ will not make it faster, nor more readable.

Comment: yeah-yeah... I meant faster to read/write code... To me reading for loops is definitely not more readable (I bet you wouldn't understand my code above without extra comments)... but as you said, is subjective

Comment: @Cristi: I see. Well, I would say that in your case, the code is faster both to read and write in the form you have written it, rather than forumlated as LINQ. When I read the code given by @Lee for instance (no offence meant), I need to think a lot more to understand than your simple for-loop (a `foreach` might be even more readable, though).

Answer (score 2):

```
var counters = Enumerable.Range(2, 13)
    .GroupJoin(playerCards, i => i, c => c, (i, cs) => new { Counter = i, Count = cs.Count() })
    .ToDictionary(p => p.Counter, p => p.Count);
```

Comment: It would have to be `Enumerable.Range(2, 13)` to get all of the cards.